# Disable onclick until JS function is done

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick

I have a PHP/JS/MySQL driven quiz site with multiple choice questions. The answer alternatives are displayed on four buttons.

```
<input type = "button" value="$alt1" onClick="changeQuestion('alternative1'); this.style.backgroundColor = '#A9A9A9'">
```

Is there any way to, when a button has been clicked, disable onclick for all buttons until the JS function is complete? As it is now, it's possible for a user to click several alternatives to one question which of course messes up the result.

The JS function called by onclick uses AJAX to call a PHP file which processes the answer.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have some sort of flag value:

```
var pending = false;

function changeQuestion(nam)
{
    // test to see if something else set the state to pending.
    // if so... return, we don't want this to happen.
    if(pending) return;
    pending = true; // raise the flag!

    /* ... later ... */
    // in the success method of your AJAX call add:
    pending = false;
```

Comment: I moved the background color change script from the button HTML and added it like this in the JS function but this seems to stop the function from running. What is wrong with it?
if(pending) return;
pending = true; // raise the flag!
document.getElementById(answer).style.backgroundColor = "#A9A9A9";

Answer (score 0):

Just run your Ajax synchronously.

In jQuery, you just need to add the async=false parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'foo.handler.php',
    data:params,
    async:false,
    success:function(){
        // do something cool.
    }
});
```